# deleting shared pointers by using an ordered map

Tags: c++

I am currently coding a shell in c++ whose file-system is implemented in main memory. I am trying to store the pointers to inodes which is either plain field or directory in a ordered map in the following manner:

```
using inode_ptr = shared_ptr<inode>;  
map<string,inode_ptr> dirents;
```

So basically the string will map either a file or a directory. For the rm "remove function", what I am trying to do is to deallocate what the pointer points to and the pointer itself by using delete:

```
void directory::remove (const string& filename) {
   DEBUGF ('i', filename);
   delete dirents[filename];
   dirents.erase(filename);
}
```

So basically, I deallocate the object and the pointer, and then delete it from the map; however, I am getting a compiler error which states the following:

```
 error: type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<inode> >::mapped_type {aka class std::shared_ptr<inode>}’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
    delete dirents[filename];
```

what am I doing wrong?

I also think that somehow the idea is wrong because the deletion of a directory has to be recursive. Eliminating  what the ptr points to doesn't get rid of the whole chain; however, I don't know if that's true.

Comment: dont do the delete - the shared_ptr will do it for you (thats what they are for). Just the erase

Comment: The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:

the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed;
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().

Comment: how do I destroy the ptr?

Comment: As pm100 pointed out you can call the `erase` function of `map`(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) to remove the `shared_ptr` from the list. If this was the last one pointing to your inode object, the object get's deleted.

Comment: [Going X-Y here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Based on your usage of it, `shared_ptr` may not be the right smart pointer for you. If you want the object to be destroyed when removed from the map, consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the try of deleting a `std::shared_ptr<T>`. You do not perfom a `delete` on that object. The destructor of it does what you really want for you. Simply call `erase` on your map at specified key and, while you erase that object, the destructor will automatically `delete` the content if there are no remaining `shared_ptr`s referencing this allocation (*very good point* ***user4581301*** ).*

Your function would look like that:

```
void directory::remove (const string& filename) {
   DEBUGF ('i', filename);
   dirents.erase(filename); // erasing that object makes it call a delete on content
}
```

EDIT: Just some quick tip - if your `map` provides the only way of accessing those pointers, consider using `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

*if you really want to perform a `delete` there, I would highly encourage you to switch to unique pointers. Usage of shared ones indicates that there might be some other pointers pointing to the memory you want to deallocate. If that's the case - your original approach was not correct. Either use `std::unique_ptr` here or don't assume you could delete the content of the `ptr`s.

Comment: Another question that's often worth asking is probably if one could not replace the `std::unique_ptr<inode>` by `inode`, if it only appears in the map and `inode`s are not huge ressources. Sometimes people use pointers without a good reason.

Comment: Recommend a slight modification just to dot the 'i's and cross the 't's:  "the destructor will automatically delete the content *if there are no remaining `shared_ptr`s referencing this allocation.*"

Comment: Great point. Added an adnotation regarding your modification. Since OP wanted to explicitly `delete` the content, usage of `std::shared_ptr<T>` wouldn't be recommended here

Comment: @Fureeish One more question. Since we are using shared pointers as reference to other inodes, we don't have to worry about recursion because deleting a directory entails deleting all its shared pointers, so automatically all the other inodes in the chain will be deleted as well.

Comment: " because deleting a directory entails deleting all its shared pointers" - no. You cannot delete a shared pointer. You can destroy the object itself, which **if, and only if, there are no more `shared_ptr`s pointing to the content of previously mentioned pointer**, will perform a `delete` on the content.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "you cannot" delete a shared pointer. We can destroy them right?

Comment: std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:

the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed;
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().

Comment: "We can destroy them right?" - yes. We can destroy shared pointers, but that does not mean that the object pointed by that pointer will be `delete`d. It will only be deleted **if no other shared pointer point to it**

Comment: I understand that. That's my point. if we delete a directory, we destroy all the shared pointer that this directory contains. If that happens, then all the objects referenced by these pointers will be destroyed since there are no more pointers referencing them. This will provoke a chain deletion throughout the subtree that starts from "that" directory